# Is there any way to link two servers in nodejs (expressjs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two servers

http://127.0.0.1:7777/

http://127.0.0.1:7778/

I'm trying to link the actions of these two servers.

For example, when I click on server 7778 I create a folder and put an action that detects the file create

```
var fs = require('fs');
   if (fs.existsSync('/home/diegonode/Desktop/ExpressCart-master/New')) {
       console.log("hello");
 }
```

but I use an app like this and this command only works when it is included in router get

How can I link the actions of these two servers?

```
   var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
     var common = require('./common');

      // The homepage of the site
     router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
         var number_products =         req.config.get('application').number_products_index ? req.config.get('application').number_products_index : 8;

req.db.products.find({    product_published: { $in: [ 'true'  , 'true2'] },       }).limit(3).exec(function (err, results) {
    res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Shop', 
         results: results, 
         session: req.session,
         message: clear_session_value(req.session, "message"),
         message_type: clear_session_value(req.session, "message_type"),
         config: req.config.get('application'),
         helpers: req.handlebars.helpers,
         page_url: req.config.get('application').base_url,
         show_footer: "show_footer"
    });
});
  });
```

please help me

**I REFER how I can click action  (or another type of action) of one server and detect this click in another server**

I refer use router get from another server, not from the actual server and get I do a some action
router.get( ('http://127.0.0.1:7778/data '),

Comment: Can you add some more explanation?

Comment: i refer use router get from another server not from actual server and get i do a some action router.get( ('http://127.0.0.1:7778/data '),

Comment: this action is when i click some link

Comment: this action only works if server is 7777 not 7778

Comment: So you want to catch what `routes are hit on 7777` server? You want to catch them in any other server?

Comment: yes i want catch from another server

Comment: for doing action when click button of another server

Comment: the click event should send an ajax request to server 1, then forward that request to server 2. It sounds like you should be looking into proxies https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy. There is also an example on the node website https://nodejs.org/api/http.html